# Printing url adds double forward slashes at beginning

Tags: octobercms

```
{{ url('/') }}
{{ this.page.baseFileName|app }}
{{ ''| page }}
{{ ''| page(false) }}
{{ ''| page({ filter_slug:slug_var, filter_id:id_var }) }}
```

=

```
//localhost:8080
//localhost:8080/realisaties
//localhost:8080/realisaties
//localhost:8080/realisaties
//localhost:8080/realisaties
```

Whatever I do, it always puts double forward slashes at start of url.
1. Why does it do that?
2. How can I fix this?

I have internal links on the same page smooth scrolling with javascript but I can't test it like this

Set up with gulp - browsersync and connectPHP

Comment: can you also add output what it output when you use them as `{{ ''| page }}` will give you absolute full url so ..

Comment: @HardikSatasiya I have updated the question with the results of the prints